# Syntax error with constants in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I'm trying to make a debugging class for one of my websites, something similar to the logger class in Java.

```
<?php

abstract class DebugLevel
{
    const Notice = 1;
    const Info = 2;
    const Warning = 4;
    const Fatal = 8;
}

class Debug
{
    private static $level = DebugLevel::Fatal | DebugLevel::Warning | DebugLevel::Info | DebugLevel::Notice;


}

?>
```

I get a `Parse error`:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ',' or ';' in (script path) on line 13
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add logic to a class property (variable) or constant in PHP.

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.

---

To set such a value use the `__construct()` function.

```
class Debug {

    public $level; // can not be a constant if you want to change it later!!!

    public function __construct() {
        $this->level = DebugLevel::Fatal | DebugLevel::Warning | DebugLevel::Info | DebugLevel::Notice;
    }

}
```

or maybe more elegant:

```
class Debug {

    public $level; // can not be a constant if you want to change it later!!!

    public function setLevel($level) {
        $this->level = $level;
    }

}
```

Then you can call this by:

```
$Debug = new Debug();
$Debug->setLevel(DebugLevel::Warning);
```

Comment: So how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti: Use the `__construct()` function. We don't appreciate spoon-feeders here. Using `__construct()` is very straightforward.

Comment: When I posted the comment, he hadn't already written to use `__construct()`.